# MySQL AFTER INSERT Trigger - select INTO using NEW values not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert-into

In MySQL:

1. I have an `interview` table, and
2. when a new interview is created (a row inserted into `interview`),
3. I want to add rows to a child table `interview_questions` table linking to the question definitions in `interview_questions_template`.

I'm trying to do this in an AFTER INSERT trigger on `interview`, and mysql is saying I have a syntax error at the end of my INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement.

I've tried joining with NEW, thinking it might be a table, but that didn't work either. Gander at the code?

```
CREATE TRIGGER interview_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON interview 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO interview_questions (id_interview, id_candidate, id_question_def,  s_userid)
    SELECT NEW.id_interview, NEW.id_candidate, interview_question_template.id_question_def, NEW.s_userid 
        FROM interview_question_template;

END
```

The error mysqlworkbench is showing is "missing 'semicolon'", underlining interview_question_template after the FROM.

The execution error says there is an error on that line after ' '.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine. Just wrap the whole thing in a delimiter block. The below survives the 1064 Error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER interview_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON interview 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO interview_questions (id_interview, id_candidate, id_question_def,  s_userid)
    SELECT NEW.id_interview, NEW.id_candidate, interview_question_template.id_question_def, NEW.s_userid 
        FROM interview_question_template;

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

As for the importance of Delimiters, see the bottom of [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905535) of mine. I wrote it more eloquently elsewhere, just can't find a reference to it. And the mysql manual has little about it with any verbosity for the average human.

I am sorry for posting the obvious. Sometimes people just have to see it :P

Comment: That did it! **Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

The other thing I did was to simply remove the BEGIN/END and it also worked like a charm.